# Implement coroutine in terms of async def

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

The following example defines a coroutine `multiply`, which waits for a value, multiplies it by a constant factor, and prints the result. Another function, `product_table`, uses `multiply` to produce product tables.

```
def multiply(factor):
    print(f"product table for {factor}")
    while True:
        sent_value = yield
        result = factor * sent_value
        print(f"{factor} x {sent_value} = {result}")

def product_table(coro):
    coro.send(None) # start coroutine
    for value in range(1, 11):
        coro.send(value)

product_table(multiply(3))
```

running the example produces:

```
product table for 3
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2 = 6
3 x 3 = 9
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27
3 x 10 = 30
```

I am trying to implement the exact same example in terms of `async def` and `await`, but I'm getting nowhere. My original, incorrect expectation was that the following coroutine function using `await` was equivalent to the coroutine relying on `yield`:

```
async def multiply(factor):
    print(f"product table for {factor}")
    while True:
        await sent_value
        result = factor * sent_value
        print(f"{factor} x {sent_value} = {result}")
```

It may sound stupid that I expected this to work, but to my dull brain it reads "wait for the sent value". This is not the case -- I get `NameError: name 'sent_value' is not defined`.

So far, my limited understanding is that you can define coroutine functions in terms of `yield` (as in the first, working example), **or** in terms of `async def` and `await`, as I attempted in the second example. This does not seem to be the case.

My concrete questions are:

1. How would you implement the first example in terms of `async def`?
2. Does it even make sense to implement in terms of `async def`?

I hate that all the freaking examples I've found are in terms of *fake* pipelines that use `time.sleep(0.1)` everywhere. I'm trying to make a blog post with examples that use more concrete (if also trivial) pipelines.

[removed erroneous edit]

Comment: `async def` started out as syntactic sugar, yes, to make it easier to spot that you have a coroutine (as `def functionname()` does not communicate that somewhere in the body there's a `yield` or `yield from`). I'm putting this in the comments because that part of your question is tangental to your actual issue and makes your question borderline too broad. I'd take it out.

Comment: What you implemented in your edit doesn't work: *TypeError: object range can't be used in 'await' expression*. A `range()` object is not an awaitable.

Comment: Shoot --- I ran the wrong file... editing...

Comment: Concrete example: build a web service that aggregates information from a bunch of different sources, then ranks those in a list. Say you have a bunch of REST APIs to call, some databases, some file data to process, then aggregate all that and run some rankers on those, then finally sort the results. That's an excellent use-case for awaitables, because you can *wait for data to appear in parallel*. That's basically how the Facebook and Instagram news feeds work..

Comment: See https://github.com/Instagram/django-workload/blob/master/django-workload/django_workload/feed.py for a super-simplified implementation of such a setup.

Answer (score 3):

`await` is the same thing as *`yield from`*, not `yield`; it *delegates control of the generator to a next one*.

You are not delegating control, so you would not use `async def` and `await`; you are merely sending data across to another generator. If an exception was being sent (with `generator.throw()`), this would not be passed on to your `multiply()` generator.

The point of `async def` is to create *awaitable* coroutines, and `await` only works with awaitables. The goal is that you can chain these together and still efficiently get information back to the event loop that drives them. `yield` is not used (or even legal) in an awaitable coroutine.

You may want to read this excellent blog post by Brett Cannon, a Python core developer, on how `async def`, `await` and `yield from` and `@asyncio.coroutine` tie together: [*How the heck does async/await work in Python 3.5?*](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/)

You *can* combine a generator with a coroutine; as of Python 3.6 (which implemented [PEP 525 - *Asynchronous Generators*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/):

```
async def multiply(factor):
    print(f"product table for {factor}")
    while True:
        sent_value = yield
        result = factor * sent_value
        print(f"{factor} x {sent_value} = {result}")
```

Note that I didn't replace the `yield` here. You'd use it like this:

```
async def product_table(coro):
    await coro.send(None) # start coroutine
    for value in range(1, 11):
        await coro.send(value)
```

There is little point in making this a coroutine, you are not using any awaitables in the `product_table()` generator. But say you wanted to send this data to a network socket instead:

```
async def multiply(factor):
    await socket.send(f"product table for {factor}")
    while True:
        sent_value = yield
        result = factor * sent_value
        await socket.send(f"{factor} x {sent_value} = {result}")
```

Now you have something that an event loop could manage for you, running multiple such tasks in parallel, sending multiplication tables to multiple clients as they are ready to receive the data.

Comment: My thinking was upside-down. So, the coroutine can receive the generator (which may or may not be asynchronous) and delegate to it on every "iteration". Kind of?

Comment: @Escualo: kind of. `await` works just like `yield from`, but has the added restriction that you have to have an awaitable object; this to prevent you from accidentally mixing old-skool generators and coroutines.

Comment: @Escualo: (and this gives Python room to optimise for coroutines being stacked together too).

Answer (score 3):

> Does it even make sense to implement in terms of async def?

No, I think it's not.

It happened that `asyncio` module was implemented using generators, but, theoretically, it could've been implemented without generators at all. There's no point of trying to use asyncio for generator specific job. Just imagine that asyncio coroutines and generator coroutines - are different things.

Roughly saying, you should use `asyncio` only when you need to do some I/O operations parallely (like downloading multiple urls) and for nothing else. [More about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `async def` you are creating a new type of first-class object, a coroutine object. These have to be driven by something, an asynchronous event loop. The `await` needs to call a coroutine, where it may be suspended. These are usually used for IO.

David Beazley wrote a nice framework for this, called [curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can see a basic [example echo server](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/blob/master/examples/echoserv.py).