# AWS IoT Python SDK and asyncio

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, python-asyncio, aws-iot

I need to use AWS IoT MQTT service. I am doing some experimenting with https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python currently.

My application will be using websockets to communicate with another service, and then publish / subscribe to MQTT topics to forward / receive messages.

Is it likely that this library will be blocking code execution? I still try to get my head around asyncio, and not sure what things I should be looking out for. How do I know if it will cause problems?

I believe I will only need to use [AWSIoTMQTTClient](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/blob/333ffdb00588a7bcd80b21d352d6f4f44597c9a5/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py#L34) from above library .

This is an extract from the working code I have:

```
class AWSIoTClient:

    def __init__():
        ...
        self.client = AWSIoTMQTTClient(...)

    def subscribe(self, callback):
        self.client.subscribe(f'{self.TOPIC}/subscribe/', 0, callback)

    def publish(self, message):
        self.client.publish(self.TOPIC, message, 0)


class MyWSProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def set_aws_client(self, client: AWSIoTClient):
        client.subscribe(self.customCallback)
        self.client = client

    def customCallback(self, client, userdata, message):
        # This will be called when we send message from AWS
        if message.payload:
            message = json.loads(message.payload.decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"'))
            message['id'] = self.next_id()
            self.sendMessage(json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        message = json.loads(payload)

        # This will forward message to AWS
        self.client.publish(str(payload))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it likely that this library will be blocking code execution?
>
> How do I know if it will cause problems?

You should not allow to having long-running blocking (synchronous) code inside any of your coroutines. It'll lead to blocking your global event loop and further blocking all of your coroutines everywhere.

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)  # async sleeping, it's ok

    time.sleep(3)           # synchronous sleeping, this freezes event loop 
                            # and all coroutines for 3 seconds, 
                            # you should avoid it!
    
    await asyncio.sleep(3)  # async sleeping, it's ok
```

If you need to run blocking code inside coroutine you should do it in executor ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) about it).

You should keep it in mind when you writing coroutines, but usually asyncio will warn you about this error if you'll enable [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.set_debug):

```
import asyncio
import time


async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)  # debug mode
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

You'll see warning:

```
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000002063C2521F8>(<Future finis...events.py:275>) created at C:\Users\gmn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\asyncio\futures.py:348> took 3.000 seconds
```

Comment: Will add the debug statement see if something comes up. Thank you

Comment: Hm, no errors from debug. Will keep looking, I guess I need to understand how the SDK works from its source.