# What does an "Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper..." warning in python asyncio mean

Tags: python, future, python-asyncio

The message below is being printed while setting the result of an asyncio future.

```
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc3435141f8>(<Future finis...ection.py:260>) created at /media/stuff/stuff/projects/dare/dcds/dcds/common/connection.py:221> took 1.723 seconds
```

I have no idea where even to start looking for the cause. But if I turn off the asyncio debug mode it crashes and shows me this.

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<upload.<locals>.upload_coro() done, defined at /media/stuff/stuff/projects/dare/dcds/dcds/__main__.py:58> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fdf5df01d38>()]> cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_set_state() at /home/elviento/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/futures.py:414]>
```

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I'm keeping these futures in a WeakValueDictionary. The warning and error disappears if I replace the WeakValueDictionary with a normal dictionary. I think it might have something to do with how the WeakValueDictionary destroys the futures.

Comment: I'm going to try some stuff.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. can you please explain what exactly the issue was and how you solved it.

Comment: @HimanshuJain It's been a while since I solved this problem, but if I remember correctly I solved it by changing my code so it doesn't use the weak value dictionary. The futures need to be properly closed which the dictionary wasn't doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc3435141f8>(<Future finis...ection.py:260>) created at /media/stuff/stuff/projects/dare/dcds/dcds/common/connection.py:221> took 1.723 seconds
```

Main part of this warning is `took 1.723 seconds`: warning says that some coroutine (or task) has freezed your event loop for 1.7 seconds, which is not normal situation (if you  don't see why, please read answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415716/1113207) or better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207)).

As you noted asyncio tracks this problem only when debug mode is on.

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

This warning you'll get regardless of debug mode, it means that at the moment you call `loop.close()` you still have running tasks. It's again not normal situation (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37430948/1113207) to see why).

---

It's hard to say more without reproducible code snippet.

If you store task in WeakValueDictionary it can be problem, yes. You should [properly cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810272/1113207) all tasks (or await them to be finished) before you close event loop.

Comment: if you have many coroutines, if there any way of knowing which one froze?

Comment: @TadejMagajna I'm afraid no, at least I don't know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions* of Python, you will get a bit more information on which task is holding the event loop for too long. The feature is discussed more here: https://bugs.python.org/issue38986

* Python 3.7.6 or Python 3.8.1