# How to combine sync object iteration and async code in python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a list of objects, and for each object, I need to do some async work on it. I am not sure if I construct it right:

```
def run(tasks):
    async def async_wrapper():
        async def update_task():
            updated_task = await task_manager.async_get_task_status(session, task)
            # do some works with updated_task

        workers = []
        resolver = aiohttp.AsyncResolver()
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(resolver=resolver, family=socket.AF_INET)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
            for local_task in tasks: # tasks is a list of object
                await update_ocr_task()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(aysnc_wrapper())
```

I think the for loop is sync and will totally block the progress, am I right? If I am, how to construct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def run(tasks):
    # ...

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(aysnc_wrapper())
```

Usually it's not how people write async programs: event loop should be global and be started as main entry point of whole script. Doing like you do (running event loop inside single function `run`) makes unable for upper code to run other coroutines in same event loop.

If you understand this and all you want is blocking `run` function that can't be used alongside with other async stuff, read further.

---

Problem with your `async_wrapper` is that it awaits next `update_ocr_task()` coroutine only after previous one been done. For loop is not what we call "blocking", but it's just not concurrent - it doesn't use benefits provided by asynchronous paradigm.

To achieve benefits of using asyncio you should run multiple coroutines concurrently. Common way to do it is to use [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```
async def async_wrapper():

    async def process_single_task(task):
        resolver = aiohttp.AsyncResolver()
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(resolver=resolver, family=socket.AF_INET)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
            await session.get(...) # do all job for *single* local task here.

    # Run multiple task processing coroutines concurrently:
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[process_single_task(t) for t in tasks]
    )
```

If you want you can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) little answer about asyncio in general.

Comment: Oh, I think I have noticed what's wrong. `await update_ocr_task()` is concurrent with other coroutines such as `await task_manager.async_get_task_status(session, task)`, but not itself. `gather` makes all `update_ocr_task` concurrent. That is the point. BTW, the reason why I wrap the whole loop into a function is that I want to run async event loop in a separate thread/process as my main thread is a sync task.

Comment: A little additional question, could I just replace `for` with `async for` to accomplish the same behave?

Comment: @Sraw no. `async for` uses to iterate by asynchronous generator. It's absolutely different thing.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have understood coroutine much more.