# Can I skip "async def" in a function in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Can I skip the `async def` keyword in a Python 3.5 function, and my code will still work asynchronously?

Something like this:

```
async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def mysleep():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.await(sleep)

def main():
    mysleep()
```

Comment: No, it's impossible.

Comment: @Sraw Can you elaborate?

Comment: Try it yourself.  Python lends itself very well to experimentation, thanks to its REPL.

Comment: Yes, simpy replace `loop.await(sleep)` with `loop.run_until_complete(sleep())`.

Answer (score 4):

As Vincent noticed if you change your code like this it'll work without error:

```
import asyncio


async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def mysleep():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(sleep())

def main():
    mysleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### But does it mean it works asynchronously?

Answer is — it works asynchronously only inside `mysleep()` function (and can get related [benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) there), but it's blocking for everything outside of `mysleep()`. It means that `mysleep()` itself or any outer code can't be run asynchronously alongside with other asynchronous functions.

To avoid this situation you should run your event loop in most possible outer scope: make event loop starting at the entry point of your program. It'll make possible to run everything asynchronously inside this single event loop.