# Async generator with next

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following piece of code:

```
def is_it_bad(word):
    try:
        res = next((item for item in all_names if str(word) in str(item["name"])))
    except:
        res = {'name':word, 'gender':2}
return res
```

It looks like It is blocking my async function that is calling *is_it_bad*. I'm not very familiar with async, is there any way to make this function non-blocking?

Function calling *is_it_bad*:

```
async def get_genders_by_dict(res):
    letters = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z\ ]')
    fname = unidecode(str(letters.sub('', res['full_name'])).lower())
    fname = letters.sub('', res['username']).lower() + ' ' + fname + ' ' + fname.replace(' ', '')
    fname = fname.split(' ')    
    genders = []
    for j in fname:
        if len(j) > 2:
            print(j)
            genders.append(is_it_bad_tst('_' + j + '_')['gender'])
            for k in genders:
                if int(k) != 2:
                    gender = k
                    print('GOOD: ', '_' + j + '_', gender)


async def get_genders_by_dict_main(loop):
    tasks = [get_genders_by_dict(res) for res in results]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_genders_by_dict_main(loop))
```

Comment: Can you please add part of the code that is calling `is_it_bad` function.

Comment: @SumitJha Sorry, added

Comment: What python version are you using? What is all_names(is it a big sequence)?

Comment: @fabiocerqueira python 3.6.4  
all_names = [{'gender': 0.0, 'name': '_aaralyn_'},
 {'gender': 1.0, 'name': '_aaric_'}] It has around 20 000 items

Answer (score 2):

> make this function non-blocking?

In context of `asyncio` blocking function is a function that spends much time waiting for network-related operations (when you're requesting something from web) or a function that spends much CPU-time (long calculations).

Usually you can use `asyncio` to run network-related operations concurrently that allows to get results faster. `asyncio` can't somehow speedup CPU-related operations other than running them in [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor) (pool of processes) to get benefit of multiple cores. Latter however can be achieved with pure [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example), without `asyncio` at all.

As far as I can tell your code is none of the described situations: `get_genders_by_dict` has nothing to do with network and it doesn't seem to contain long-running calculations that can be parallelized on multiple cores.
 Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) for detailed explanations.

Long story short, if I'm not missing something you don't need `asyncio` at all, there's just no sense to use it. Just make `get_genders_by_dict` a plain function and use it so.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your code is that you are doing CPU bounded call and it can block the reactor(loop), I think the better way to solve your problem is using multiprocessing or just using a wrapper to run the tasks in an executor(another process)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

Comment: I have tried with ThreadPoolExecutor - no difference in time compared to plain for loop. I believe I need an async generator function to replace current *is_it_bad*