# Python Async Functionality

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to figure out how the async functionality works in Python.  I have watched countless videos but I guess I'm not 'getting it'.  My code looks as follows:

```
def run_watchers():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(watcher_helper())
    loop.close()

async def watcher_helper():
    watchers = Watcher.objects.all()

    for watcher in watchers:
        print("Running watcher : " + str(watcher.pk))
        await watcher_helper2(watcher)

async def watcher_helper2(watcher):
    for i in range(1,1000000):
        x = i * 1000 / 2000
```

What makes sense to me is to have three functions.  One to start the loop, second to iterate through the different options to execute and third to do the work.

I am expecting the following output:

```
Running watcher : 1
Running watcher : 2
...
...

Calculation done
Calculation done
...
...
```

however I am getting:

```
Running watcher : 1
Calculation done
Running watcher : 2
Calculation done
...
...
```

which obviously shows the calculations are not done in parallel.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mixing Django models (`Watcher`) with asyncio code kills concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio` can be used only to speedup multiple network I/O related functions (send/receive data through internet). While you wait some data from network (which may take long time) you usually idle. Using `asyncio` allows you to use this idle time for another useful job: for example, to start another parallel network request.

`asyncio` can't somehow speedup CPU-related job (which is what `watcher_helper2` do in your example). While you multiply some numbers there's simply no idle time which can be used to do something different and to achieve benefit through that.

Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying.  I replaced the watcher_helper2 with the dummy code which does not make sense to use in async mode.  For my case I found the solution, which is to use asyncio.wait(tasks)