# Why won't my Python async / await actually write matplotlib files?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-asyncio

My code is:

```
import os
import h5py
import asyncio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

data_path = os.environ['DATA_PATH']
output_data_path = os.environ['OUTPUT_DATA_PATH']
patient_files = os.listdir(data_path)


async def save_file(filename, image_data):
    plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
    await plt.savefig(filename, pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')

for patient_file in patient_files:
    patient_parts = patient_file.split('.')
    patient_parts = patient_parts[0].split('_')
    patient_id = patient_parts[1]
    if int(patient_id) < 21:
        continue
    print('Doing patient', patient_id)

    patient_data = h5py.File(os.path.join(data_path, patient_file))
    variables = patient_data.items()

    for var in variables:
        name = var[0]
        data = var[1]

        if type(data) is h5py.Dataset:
            value = data.value
            plt.axis('off')
            if name == 'Svar25':
                for layer in range(value.shape[0]):
                    output_file = os.path.join(
                        output_data_path, patient_id + '_FLAIR_debone_' + str(layer) + '.png')
                    save_file(filename=output_file, image_data=value[layer])

            if name == 'Svar24':
                for layer in range(value.shape[0]):
                    output_file = os.path.join(
                        output_data_path, patient_id + '_FLAIR_bone_' + str(layer) + '.png')
                    save_file(filename=output_file, image_data=value[layer])
```

I'm trying to write my files asynchronously, but it doesn't actually write.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
await plt.savefig(filename, pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Function doesn't become async just because you use `await` before it. You have to [declare](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) function as `async def` to make it async in the first place.

Any function that uses `await` should be defined as `async def` up to entry point of your program (like `async def main()`). You should [run entry point in event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) to make async code work.

Both functions `plt.imshow` and `plt.savefig` are sync by their nature. You can try to cast second one to async using [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and awaiting for result, but I'm not sure if it'll work. I'm also not sure if you need it: you probably won't achieve any speedup paralleling these disk I/O operations.

---

Long story short, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) to better understand why people use asyncio in the first place. I also advice you to read [this part of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and starting with more trivial async task.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `await` ahead of `save_file(...)`. That means the asyncio loop will never schedule the file writing function.

Very common mistake in my experience...

Update: From your comment, it appears you never kick off the asyncio loop to process functions. You'll need to start the top level function, as per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run). Python 3.7 has a nice new simple syntax, the principle is the same in 3.5 and 3.6 but a bit more long-winded.

```
>>> import asyncio

>>> async def main():
...     print('hello')
...     await asyncio.sleep(1)
...     print('world')

>>> asyncio.run(main())
hello
world
```

Comment: Do I have to make my entire code somehow `async` then?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, async does tend to spread like a virus through your code. You need to kick off the asyncio loop. Then you can do cool stuff like running the saves in parallel, but using a single thread.

Comment: My main code isn't in a function, so how can I kick off the `async` portion?

Comment: You'll need to put it in a function. Global variables and async is kind of asking for trouble anyhow ;)