# Get an iterable generator from an async generator

Tags: generator, python-3.7, python-asyncio

I have an async generator that I'm trying to pass into a keras model fit_generator, but the async generator returns an object, not a generator.

I've tried googling, but I haven't found a solution. This seems to be a pretty specific problem.

Comment: Have you tried collecting the generator into a list and passing that into the model? You can use an async list comprehension for that, e.g. `lst = [x async for x in bla()]`

Comment: Yes, however, I have tens of millions of rows of data so I was trying to find a way to do async generator -> generator.

Comment: Can you do it in batches? Barring magic with threads, non-async code will never be able to handle an async generator.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164899/1600898) for the threaded approach, but batching is probably a simpler option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intention of `asyncio` to split async generator from regular generator, read answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56525798/1113207).

However if you decided that you won't run async generator concurrently elsewhere and your only intention is to avoid RAM overflow, you can cast async generator to regular one [manually](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator) iterating async generator and awaiting each new item:

```
import asyncio


async def my_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


def to_sync_generator(ait):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                coro = ait.__anext__()
                res = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                return
            else:
                yield res
    finally:
        coro = loop.shutdown_asyncgens()
        loop.run_until_complete(coro)


# Check:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in to_sync_generator(my_gen()):
        print(i)
```

**P.S.** Didn't test code much.