# How can I convert AsyncIterator to Iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to wrap a function around an AsyncIterator to get a (sync) Iterator?

I was able to convert an AsyncIterator to List and use it as an Iterator, but would love to not do the conversion to Int

```
class AsyncToSyncIterableUtils(Generic[T]):

    @staticmethod
    def sync_all(iterable: AsyncIterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
        results:List[T] = []
        async def _wrapper():
            async for m in iterable:
                results.append(m)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(_wrapper())
        finally:
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens()) # see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_asyncgens
            loop.close()
        return results
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap asyncio with iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132673/how-to-wrap-asyncio-with-iterator)