# How to use csv.reader in an async context?

Tags: python, csv, python-asyncio, httpx

I query multiple services with asynchronously using `httpx`. These services return csv data that could be very large so I'm using [streams](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#streaming-responses).

So far so good.

The problem I'm having is that the Python standard `csv.reader` doesn't work with `AsyncIterator`'s and the async stream won't let you call the sync functions like `iter_lines()`. Doing that gets you the following error:

> RuntimeError: Attempted to call a sync iterator on an async stream.

So you're stuck with the async functions like `aiter_lines()` which return an `AsyncIterator`.

I've seen `aiocsv` but that can't be used with `AsyncIterator`'s since it expects an object with a `read(size: int)`.

Example code below:

```py
from httpx import AsyncClient
from csv import reader

async with AsyncClient() as client:
    async with client.stream("POST", url, content=query, headers=HEADER, timeout=25) as resp:
        lines = resp.aiter_lines()
        await anext(lines) # skip headers

        for line in reader(lines):
             yield QueryResult(*line) # create namedtuple for ease of use
```

> TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap asyncio with iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132673/how-to-wrap-asyncio-with-iterator)