# How to check if function is blocking or not?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm using asynchronous workflow with synchronous code within it. How do I check, if synchronous functions are blocking or not, to be sure that nothing breaks during execution.

```py
async def download_upload_xmls_async(message,count,id,conn1,cursor1,conn2,cursor2):
    # SOME CODE
    xml = await req(urlX, headers)

    print('Got message')

    write(message_count, id, conn1, cursor1)
    print('Wrote progress')

    send_message("Send" + xml, id, conn2, cursor2)
    print('Sent message')

    write_locally(data)

    await message.ack()
```

In code above, how do I check, that functions write and send_message are non-blocking? They work with db, that i cannot access to check if everything works as expected. Also can I assume, that if function write_locally works correctly, that my previous functions also worked correctly?

Functions write and send_message do almost same thing - they take data and execute query on PostgreSQL db using connection and cursor passed to them. Function write_locally makes writes to csv file.

```py
def send_message(message, id, con, cur, **nargs):
    params = {
              #some params
             }
    union_params= {**params, **nargs}
    data = json.dumps(union_params, ensure_ascii=False)
    cur.execute(
                #Query
                )
    con.commit()
```

Also i have to add, that connection and cursor were created with aiopg, so all their methods are coroutines.

Comment: Can you check the code of `send_message` `write` etc?

Comment: This question is hard to answer right now. Where are `write` and `send_message` coming from? Did you write them? In general, you should assume that functions do what they are documented to do.

Comment: @DroidX86 Added additional info on those functions

Comment: Sounds like your functions are blocking. Post the definitions for confirmation. Async functions would start with `async def` instead of just `def`

Comment: @DroidX86 Added that. Please note the last statement also.

Comment: Yeah that's a blocking call.

Comment: @DroidX86 So, it won't work as intended? Even if last function does the job? Thank you for your patience, btw.

Comment: Any blocking call within your async functions will block the thread executing your event loop. That's why you need something like: https://github.com/hellysmile/asyncio_monkey -

Comment: @ЭльмирЭльмир consider reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) and commentaries under it. I think it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection and cursor have coroutine methods, then `send_message` as written will not block the event loop.

However, it won't *do* anything because it fails to *await* the coroutines it calls. It needs to be defined with `async def` and it needs to `await` the calls to `cur.execute(...)` and `cur.commit()`. `download_upload_xmls_async` similarly fails to await `send_message`. Correct code should look like this:

```py
async def download_upload_xmls_async(message, count, id, conn1, cursor1, conn2, cursor2):
    ... some code here ...
    # note the await
    await send_message("Send" + xml, id, conn2, cursor2)
    # write_locally doesn't need to be a coroutine because
    # it (presumably) doesn't block    
    write_locally(data)
    await message.ack()

# note "async def"
async def send_message(message, id, con, cur, **nargs):
    params = {
              #some params
             }
    union_params= {**params, **nargs}
    data = json.dumps(union_params, ensure_ascii=False)
    # note the await
    await cur.execute(
                #Query
                )
    await con.commit()
```