# When using asyncio.run, how do I submit the threadpool executor to the event loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, threadpoolexecutor

In the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop), it states:

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio
> functions, such as asyncio.run(), and should rarely need to reference
> the loop object or call its methods.
>
> Consider also using the asyncio.run() function instead of using lower
> level functions to manually create and close an event loop.

If I need to use `asyncio` and a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, how would I submit the executor to the event loop?

Normally you could do:

```
   # Create a limited thread pool.
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
        max_workers=3,
    )

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(
            run_blocking_tasks(executor)
        )
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate why do you need `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Running multiple event loops in threads won't speedup thing due to GIL. | Or maybe you want to run some blocking operation while event loop is running? In this case you should pass `ThreadPoolExecutor` into `run_in_executor` like shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). | In case written above is confusing, consider reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207).

Comment: You can replace the last seven lines with `asyncio.run(run_blocking_task(executor))`. That is equivalent to the code you posted, but avoids manual teardown of the event loop. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov - I found that exact sample (Python docs) moments after I posted the question. It answered what I was looking for.