# Is there ever a reason to `return await ...` in python asyncio?

Tags: python, async-await, return, python-asyncio

I know in js it doesn't add anything to do an `await` before a `return` statement (i.e. `return await ...`), but is it the case in python too, or this somehow makes the materialization more probable or different?

If the two are not equivalent, what is the best practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use and when not to use Python 3.5 \`await\` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357233/when-to-use-and-when-not-to-use-python-3-5-await)

Comment: @shaikmoeed this question is much more specific and deserves its own answer (in js there's a linter to prevent this pattern, which illustrates people are thinking about this specific thing).

Comment: @Uri "I know in js it doesn't add anything to do an await before a return statement" This is not true, even though quite close. Read this: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/ Thus the rule of thumb should be: always `await`. I'm not sure how Python handles it, but Js is just a shitty language that does lots of implicit, counterintuitive and hard-to-debug things behind the scene.

Comment: In Haskell `return` is what wraps a value in a Monad. So if your value is already async, you don't even need a return call. However in javascript and python you must always have a return call, so if you don't "unwrap" the async monad using "await" before you call return, you'll end up with a double wrapped value.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Given:

```
async def foo() -> str:
    return 'bar'
```

What you get when calling `foo` is an [*`Awaitable`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Awaitable), which obviously you'd want to `await`. What you need to think about is the return value of your function. You can for example do this:

```
def bar() -> Awaitable[str]:
    return foo()  # foo as defined above
```

There, `bar` is a synchronous function but returns an `Awaitable` which results in a `str`.

```
async def bar() -> str:
    return await foo()
```

Above, `bar` itself is `async` and results in an `Awaitable` when called which results in a `str`, same as above. There's no real difference between these two usages. Differences appear here:

```
async def bar() -> Awaitable[str]:
    return foo()
```

In that example, calling `bar` results in an `Awaitable` which results in an `Awaitable` which results in a `str`; quite different. If you naïvely use the above, you'll get this kind of result:

```
>>> asyncio.run(bar())
<coroutine object foo at 0x108706290>
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
```

As a rule of thumb, every call to an `async` must be `await`ed somewhere once. If you have two `async` (`async def foo` and `async def bar`) but no `await` in `bar`, then the caller of `bar` must `await` twice, which would be odd.

Comment: Thanks! Would it have made more sense for `asyncio` to merge the coroutines, requiring a single await? Seems like an odd design choice.

Comment: Python's mantra is *explicit is better than implicit*, so one `await` per `async` makes a whole lot of sense and leaves you in total control.

Answer (score 18):

TL)DR of @deceze answer.

Yes, there is a reason. Always `return await` from a coroutine when calling another coroutine.

`Async` functions always return an Awaitable, even with a plain `return`. You only get the actual result by calling `await`. Without `return await` the result is an extra wrapped Awaitable and must be awaited twice.  See doc.

```
import asyncio

async def nested():
    return 42

async def main():
    # Nothing happens if we just call "nested()".
    # A coroutine object is created but not awaited,
    # so it *won't run at all*.
    nested()

    # Let's do it differently now and await it:
    print(await nested())  # will print "42".

asyncio.run(main())
```