# Should I use coroutines for synchronous Code from asynchronous Code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

If I need to call some synchronous code from a coroutine, does it matter if I use a coroutine for that synchronous code?

Example: Does it matter if I use `get_hello` or `coro_get_hello`? And if not, what is the correct / preferred way?

````py
import asyncio
import re


class Foo:
    def get_hello(self, string):
        return re.findall(r"(H.+?)\n", string)

    async def coro_get_hello(self, string):
        return re.findall(r"(H.+?)\n", string)

    async def worker(self):
        my_string = "Hello\nWorld\n" * 200
        for _ in range(5):
            print(await self.coro_get_hello(my_string))
            print(self.get_hello(my_string))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        asyncio.run(self.worker())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo().start()```
````

Comment: No, it doesn't help.  If you're worried about blocking the event loop, you need to either switch to an asynchronous solution, or do your blocking operation in another thread/process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main point of using `async def` / `await` is to explicitly mark places in a code where context switch can happen (where execution flow can switch to another coroutine). Lesser such places - easier to handle a concurrent code. **Thus don't make a function coroutine unless you have some reason for it.**

What reason do you have to make a function coroutine?

- If this function would need to `await` some coroutine, it should be a coroutine either
- If the function would need to `await` some [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) or other async object, it should be defined a coroutine
- If the function doesn't need to `await` for something, but it will be called inside other coroutine and calling the function [takes much time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code). In this case it makes sense to call a function [in a thread asynchronously](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and `await` the thread is finished.

You can read a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) (and in discussion under the answer).

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's much clearer now. Especially point 3 I was worrying about.