# how to understand await in coroutines?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Following example shows we can run phase1 then run phase2. But what we wanted with coroutine is to do two things concurrently instead of one after another. I know if I use asyncio.get_event_loop.create_task can achieve what I want, but why use await? I think there is no difference between using await and just using the plain function.

```
import asyncio


async def outer():
    print('in outer')
    print('waiting for result1')
    result1 = await phase1()
    print('waiting for result2')
    result2 = await phase2(result1)
    return (result1, result2)


async def phase1():
    print('in phase1')
    return 'result1'


async def phase2(arg):
    print('in phase2')
    return 'result2 derived from {}'.format(arg)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    return_value = event_loop.run_until_complete(outer())
    print('return value: {!r}'.format(return_value))
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried not using `await` here? You'll see that it is not equivalent

Comment: equivalent, if I delete the two await and two async

Comment: Consider kindly to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207). I think it contains answer to your question.